# MySQL Select Data from 2 Tables With Unique ID in one Query

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have 2 tables with the following structure

```
streams [ id , stream_name ]
movies  [ id, movie_name   ]
```

These 2 tables have unique ids that means the same id can't exists on both of them. Now, i would like to GET with one query and with the Given id the stream_name or movie_name.

In a few words i want to select the column (stream_name OR movie_name) where the id is found.

How i can do that using one Query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Union:

```
select stream_name as name from streams where id=<id>
Union
select movie_name as name from movies where id=<id>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all [unique](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) referres to tables not the entire database therefore it is completely valid for streams.id and movies.id to have the same number.

What you are looking for is

```
select streams.name, movies.name
from streams inner join movies
on streams.id = movies.id;`
```

you can learn more about joins in this [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)